# Screen Flicker after installing HyperV on Windows 10 Dell Laptop

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, drivers

I've got a new Dell Inspiron 17 (7779) laptop with Windows 10 x64 (1703) which was working fine right up until the point where HyperV was installed. Now the host screen flickers like mad even with no Guest VM's created.

Dell are being particularly unhelpful, so I was wondering is anyone else was having the same issue.

Basically is anyone running Hyper V on a dell Inspiron successfully.

I guess it could also be a clash with the display drivers (Intel HD Graphics 620, driver ver 21.20.16.4627)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I've resolved this with the [latest Intel graphics drivers 21.20.16.4678](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26836/Graphics-Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-45-?product=96551), however there were a few issues...

So the Intel drivers (21.20.16.4627) installed on the machine were the ones installed via the Dell Driver Detect tool, if you just download the latest drivers from intel and install them, it wont update them....I think there is some versioning issue with the dell drivers, as it seems to think the existing drivers are newer than the ones your trying to install....

In order to make it accept the new drivers you need to uninstall the existing display driver AND delete the install files. Then after a re-boot the display drivers used should be the default Microsoft ones, you can then upgrade the driver (again via computer manager) selecting the location of the downloaded and unzipped intel drivers.

I'd like to be able to thank Dell for there help, but they failed miserably to provide any.

[image]

One last thing...

For some reason windows automatically 'upgrade' the display drivers and re-installed a old version (21.20.16.4627) replacing the latest drivers I installed. I then had to rollback the automatic update, which fixed the issue again. Hopefully I won't have to keep doing this...

It looks like someone has made a mess of versioning some of these updates, its difficult to tell whether its an issue with the Intel drivers or the Dell wrapping of them as part of the driver detect tool, but there's definitely an issue.